# How to mimic this ApiExplorer feature "Use this resource in one of the following methods"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

[Google ApiExplorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) has a cool feature to explore other methods from a given result.

Is it possible to reproduce this feature when I develop a custom API on Google Cloud Endpoints ?

This is a working example when I use Google Bigquery Api (or any other Google Api) :
[image]

But when I try my custom api in Google ApiExplorer, the contextual menu doesn't show up.

Comment: In your custom API, do you have a method that outputs the same type as a second method uses as input? I assume that this only works within the same API, quite possibly only for types that have a "kind" field.

Comment: Yes I return a java bean, and other api methods take the same bean as input.